# hide span when data is blank using inline css

Tags: css, inline, inline-styles

my name: [$name]

How to make the “**my name:**” not visible if the "**[$name]**" is blank? I’m using inline css because this form will be sent to HTML email.

Comment: I don't think you can do it using CSS only, as it's a DOM Manipulation task.

Comment: What exactly is your HTML structure? You mention a span but do not show the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading [ask] and posting a [mre] of your code so we can give you some advice on how to proceed :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to use CSS only, it depends on the HTML structure. It is possible though.

```css
.nameContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 0.5em
}

.name:empty + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nameContainer">
  <span class="name"></span><span>My name:</span>
</div>

<div class="nameContainer">
  <span class="name">John Doe</span><span>My name:</span>
</div>
```